# wordpress setting option page data show by the jquery and ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am a wordpress developer. I am trying to develop a wordpress plugin. I used the following code for my wordpress plugin. this code is used to save data, which works perfectly. But I would like to fetch that data using Ajax. I did not find any way please anyone can give me any idea?

```
class TestAjaxSettingsAPI {
        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'rak_admin_menu' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'rak_register_settings') );
        }
    
        public function rak_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'rak menu', 'rak menu', 'manage_options', 'rak-menu', array( $this, 'rak_dashboard_page' ), '', 99 );
    
        }
    
        public function rak_dashboard_page() {
            ?>
            <form id="rak-form-submit" action="options.php" method="post">
        
                <?php
                settings_errors( 'rak_settings_fields' );
                wp_nonce_field( 'rak_dashboard_save', 'rak_form_save_name' ); // CHECK THIS AT THE END
                settings_fields( 'rak_settings_fields' );
                ?>
        
                <div id="rak-tab1" class="rak-tabcontent">
                    <?php do_settings_sections( 'rak_settings_section_tab1' ); ?>
                </div>
        
                <?php
                submit_button(
                    __( 'Save Changes', 'rak' ),
                    '',
                    'rak_save_changes_btn',
                    true,
                    array( 'id' => 'rak-save-changes-btn' )
                );
        
                if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
                    wp_die();
                }
                ?>
            <div id="rak-success-message"></div>
         
            </form>
    
            <script>
                function rakAjaxSubmit() {
                   var rakFormData = new FormData(this);
                    rakFormData.append('rak_save_changes_btn', 1);
                    // rakFormData.append('security', rak_public_ajax.rak_publisher_name);
    
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'options.php' ); ?>',
                        data: rakFormData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function () {
                            //console.log('work');
                         jQuery('#rak-success-message').html('Data saved successfully');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                         jQuery('#rak-success-message').html('Data save failed');
                        }
                    });
    
                    return false;
                }
    
                jQuery('#rak-form-submit').submit(rakAjaxSubmit);
            </script>
        
            <?php
            if ( ! isset( $_POST['rak_form_save_name'] ) ||
                 ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['rak_form_save_name'], 'rak_dashboard_save' ) ) {
                return;
            }
            ?>
           
            <?php
        }
    
        public function rak_settings_section_callback() {}
    
        public function rak_section_id_name() {
            // get the value of the setting we've registered with register_setting()
            $setting = get_option('rak_settings_fields');
            // output the field
            ?>
            <input type="text" name="rak_settings_fields[first_name]" value="<?php echo isset( $setting['first_name'] ) ? esc_attr( $setting['first_name'] ) : ''; ?>">
    
            
            <?php
        }
    
     public function rak_last_name_field() {
        $setting = get_option('rak_settings_fields');
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="rak_settings_fields[last_name]" value="<?php echo isset($setting['last_name']) ? esc_attr($setting['last_name']) : ''; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    
    
        public function rak_register_settings() {
    
            register_setting( 'rak_settings_fields', 'rak_settings_fields' );
        
            // Adding sections
            add_settings_section( 'rak_section_id', __( 'General', 'rak' ), array(
                $this,
                'rak_settings_section_callback'
            ), 'rak_settings_section_tab1' );
        
            add_settings_field( 'rak_section_id_name', __( 'First name :', 'rak' ), array(
                $this,
                'rak_section_id_name'
            ), 'rak_settings_section_tab1', 'rak_section_id' );
    
                // Adding 'Last Name' field
            add_settings_field( 'rak_section_id_last_name', __( 'Last Name:', 'rak' ), array(
                $this,
                'rak_last_name_field'
            ), 'rak_settings_section_tab1', 'rak_section_id' );
        }
    }
 
    new TestAjaxSettingsAPI();
```

Data fetching code

```
<?php 
        $options = get_option( 'rak_settings_fields', array() ); echo $options['last_name'];
        $options = get_option( 'rak_settings_fields', array() ); echo $options['first_name'];
        ?>
```